# inifinispan failed to load configured transaction manager

Tags: spring-boot, infinispan

configuring infinspan replicated cache by xml

cache manager configuration

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedCacheManager embeddedCacheManager() throws Exception {
        InfinispanEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean r = new InfinispanEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        r.setConfigurationFileLocation(new ClassPathResource("infinispan-distribution.xml"));
        r.afterPropertiesSet();
        EmbeddedCacheManager object = r.getObject();
        object.startCaches("mimi");
        return object;
    }
```

```
<replicated-cache name="mimi" mode="SYNC">
           <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
           <transaction transaction-manager-lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"
                        locking="PESSIMISTIC" mode="FULL_XA"/>
       </replicated-cache>
```

running on spring boot 1.4 ( cant upgrade )
infinispan version 8.2

transaction manager fails and set to DEfault transaction manager
Util.loadClass("com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager", classLoader) throws NullPointerException

added

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

did not solve.

exception message

```
Unable to instantiate class com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager
```